# Unity - What does a script on a prefab represent?

Tags: unity-game-engine

If you have a Serialized Field of a class derived from Monobehaviour, and a prefab that also has the class attached to it, then the Editor allows you to drag this prefab into that slot, and now the field references to the script on that prefab.
But this doesn't make sense to me. What does a script on some stored data represent?
I thought I understood the use of prefabs. But this confuses me again.

Comment: I think this is more a question for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Prefabs basically *are* full GameObjects and can be passed around as such. I'm not sure what referencing a script on a prefab would be *useful* for, but I don't see a reason for Unity to *deny* the access either.